# Extjs Widget/Component without x-innerhtml

Tags: extjs

How can one generate the most simple html widget with Extjs 7?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/316j

For example in this fiddle there is always the x-inner-html  added to the component. Can this be avoided? I would like to have a plain component like:

```
<div id="ext-component-1" class="x-component x-layout-auto-item" data-xid="6">This is a test</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own component that extends Ext.Widget.

Try to replace your fiddle code by this :

```js
 Ext.define('MyWidget', {
     extend: 'Ext.Widget',
     xtype: 'mywidget',
     config: {
         html: ''
     },
     element: {
         reference: 'element'
     },

     constructor: function(config) {
         this.callParent([config]);
         this.element.setHtml(this.getHtml());
         Ext.getBody().appendChild(this.element);
     }
 });

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        let view = Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'container',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'mywidget',
                html: 'Test'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to check out  `autoEl` config https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-autoEl